# Modern Apps don't have sound?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, audio, windows-10

There is no sound for all the modern apps on my PC when it's Windows 8.1. Now I upgraded it to Windows 10 and it still doesn't have sound. The desktop applications have sound.

I searched on the web and someone said it may related to Hyper-V, which I've enabled.

What cause the issue and how to resolve it? I had to use hyper-v on the PC.